# Convert list to int Python

Tags: python, list, integer

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
x= list(np.arange(1,9,0.5))
d = x + 2
print(d)
```

However the output gave this kind of error:

```
can only concatenate list not "int" to list
```

I'm trying to convert list to int using this code:

```
int(list(x))
```

But it gave another error. Can you please help me solving this. Thank you!

Comment: What output do you want? Do you want to append 2 to the list, or add 2 to each item in the list (or something else entirely)?

Comment: `d = x + 2` what do you mean by this ?

Comment: Not sure what you attempting in trying to cast a list to an int, perhaps you want to cast each element to an int?

Comment: I want to generate range of number from 1-9, then, each number will add to 2. Or d= x + 2.

Comment: I've marked a duplicate which does what you ask. However if you just keep the Numpy array (and don't convert it to a list) then you add to it directly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add 2 to each element, you need to use a map function like so:

```
d = list(map(lambda y: y + 2, x))
```

Comment: The output must be equal to: [3, 3.5, 4.0, 4. 5,......]. All numbers must be added to 2
>

Comment: I think I've got what you mean, updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

The “`TypeError: can only concatenate list (not “int”) to list`” error is raised when you try to concatenate an integer to a list.

This error is raised because only lists can be concatenated to lists. To solve this error, use the append() or the '+' method to add an item to a list.

```
d = x + [2]
#or
x.append(2)
```

Here are some other ways to do it: [link](https://flexiple.com/python-concatenate-lists/)

**EDIT:**

if you want to add 2 to every value in x:

1.`x = list(np.arange(1,9,0.5) + 2)`

or

2.`x = [i+2 for i in x]`